# Why is this matrix addition code giving the wrong answer?

Tags: c, matrix

The code below is giving the wrong answer if, for example, I enter:

```
1st Matrix 
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

2nd Matrix
2 2 2
2 2 2
2 2 2
```

It gives me this matrix sum output:

```
9 10 11
9 10 11
9 10 11
```

which is obviously wrong! I can't seem to find why?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    int r,c;
    int ir,ic;
    int matrix1[r][c];
    int matrix2[r][c];
    int finalmatrix[r][c];

    printf("Insert number of rows of the matrixes (max 10):  ");
    scanf("%d", &r);
    printf("Insert number of columns of the matrixes (max 10):  ");
    scanf("%d", &c);


    while(r!=c)
    {
    printf("The number of rows and columns are not equal, retry:\n");
    printf("Insert number of rows of the Matrix (max 10):  ");
    scanf("%d", &r);
    printf("Insert number of columns of the Matrix (max 10):  ");
    scanf("%d", &c);
    }

    for(ir=1; ir<=r; ir++)
    {
        for(ic=1; ic<=c; ic++)
        {
        printf("Insert element row %d and column %d of the first matrix: ", ir, ic);
        scanf("%d", &matrix1[ir][ic]);
        }
    }

    for(ir=1; ir<=r; ir++)
    {
        for(ic=1; ic<=c; ic++)
        {
        printf("Insert element row %d and column %d of the second matrix: ", ir, ic);
        scanf("%d", &matrix2[ir][ic]);
        }
    }

    for(ir=1; ir<=r; ir++)
    {
        for(ic=1; ic<=c; ic++)
        {
        finalmatrix[ir][ic]=matrix1[ir][ic]+matrix2[ir][ic];
        }
    }

    printf("The sum Matrix is:\n");

    for(ir=1; ir<=r; ir++)
    {
        for(ic=1; ic<=c; ic++)
        {
        printf("%d ", finalmatrix[ir][ic]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You matrix declaration goes with undefined values in r & c; at least define some default max values for them, like int r=100,c=100; even better would be to allocate matrices dynamically

Comment: thank you i initialized both variables now and it works :D

Comment: **Always** enable compiler warnings! Any modern compiler will show a warning about such situations.

Comment: Unfortunately the compiler didnt say anything (Ubuntu 16.10 - command used gcc -Wall -o name name.c guess im just unlucky.

Comment: @Olaf-- I compiled the original code with `gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fsanitize=undefined` and got no warnings. I was surprised! I value your opinion-- please tell me if you think I have gotten anything wrong in my answer below.

Comment: @DavidBowling: does adding `-O` or similar provoke warnings?  Some analysis doesn't occur without some level of optimization.

Comment: I compiled with my usual options, and got the warnings (converted to errors since I don't want to run code that the compiler is warning about): `gcc -O3   -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror ma11.c -o ma11` and the output lines (separated by '—') were:
`ma11.c: In function ‘main’:` —
`ma11.c:9:5: error: ‘c’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=uninitialized]` —
 `int matrix1[r][c];` —
`ma11.c:9:5: error: ‘r’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=uninitialized]` —
`cc1: all warnings being treated as errors`.  I use `-O3` routinely; even just `-O` produces the errors.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler-- Yes. In fact, I was just about to comment that the only way I have found so far to get a warning for this is to enable at least `-0` level optimizations: `gcc -std=c99 -O -Wall`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code fails to initialize the variables `r` and `c` before declaring the VLAs with them. You have no way of knowing what size these arrays are, or if `r` and `c` are even positive values! I am surprised that this code will even run. I ran the code that you posted, and got this runtime error:

> runtime error: variable length array bound evaluates to non-positive value -1208010352

I made the following change, and the code works:

```
int r,c;
int ir,ic;

printf("Insert number of rows of the matrixes (max 10):  ");
scanf("%d", &r);
printf("Insert number of columns of the matrixes (max 10):  ");
scanf("%d", &c);

int matrix1[r][c];
int matrix2[r][c];
int finalmatrix[r][c];
```

Output for your example:

```
The sum Matrix is:
3 4 5 
6 7 8 
9 10 11
```

According to the section of the standard about array declarators:

> the **[** and **]** may delimit an expression.... If they delimit an expression (which specifies the size of an array), the expression shall have an integer type. (ISO/IEC 9899:1999 6.7.5.2/1)
>
> If the size is an expression that is not an integer constant expression... each time it is evaluated it shall have a value greater than zero. (ISO/IEC 9899:1999 6.7.5.2/5)

So a negative value for `r` or `c`, which is very likely, results in undefined behavior, meaning that anything could happen! When I ran the code, I got a runtime error. You ran the same code, and got a different result. The behavior is undefined, so there is no telling what might happen.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution works and also i found out this works: 
    int r=100,c=100;
int ir,ic;
int matrix1[r][c];
int matrix2[r][c];
int finalmatrix[r][c]; 
printf("Insert number of rows of the matrixes (max 10):  ");
scanf("%d", &r);
printf("Insert number of columns of the matrixes (max 10):  ");
scanf("%d", &c);

so basically the error was not initializing the variables?

Comment: But how is not initializing the variables the error? Doesn't C overwrites them the moment i input r and c? So the error was basically that i was inputing the r and c values AFTER i created both matrixes and the system only updated r and c but didnt update the matrixes, that remained with old random values?

Comment: Ok so basically the advice is to ALWAYS initialize the variables when im working with arrays?

Comment: Sure! Thank you very much for your advices!

Comment: @RuggeroLatella-- you should always initialize ANY variable before you try to use it.